# How to modify SETTINGS_MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS on google chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, server-push, http2

I would like to know if it is possible to modify this parameter on google chrome, which is 1000 by default.

Thanks.

Eloy

Comment: Is it really 1,000 by default? Source?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with SPDY at all, but I did some searching around and found the following in the Chromium project:

```
// Maximum number of concurrent streams we will create, unless the server
// sends a SETTINGS frame with a different value.
const size_t kInitialMaxConcurrentStreams = 100;

// Specifies the maxiumum concurrent streams server could send (via push).
const int kMaxConcurrentPushedStreams = 1000;
```

https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/net/spdy/chromium/spdy_session.h?type=cs&q=kInitialMaxConcurrentStreams&sq=package:chromium&l=75

The value being a constant probably means it can't be changed? Does this help you in any way?

Comment: Not at all, I mean, it helped to me knowing that I could modify some file of Chromium to change this number...But I dont know which one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ;)

Comment: You would have to modify the source file and then recompile Chromium/Chrome. It would only work for your compiled version, and would not work for other users.